# Recording video with Opencv Python Multithreading

Tags: python, windows, multithreading, opencv, video-streaming

I am trying to record a video using opencv in python when doing multithreading within the thread that displays the stream on the window. I m fairly new to multithreading and I am not sure what is the reason I am unable to get a video recorded. I save a file but it does not have the stream in it. Pointers greatly appreciated.This is my code:

```
import cv2
import os
import threading
import shutil
import json
import re
import datetime
import time
now=datetime.datetime.now()



class camThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, previewName, camID):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.previewName = previewName

        self.camID = camID

    def run(self):
        print("Starting " + self.previewName)
        camPreview(self.previewName, self.camID)

def camPreview(previewName, camID):
    cv2.namedWindow(previewName)
    cam = cv2.VideoCapture(camID)
    cam.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 480)
    cam.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 720)
    if cam.isOpened():
        rval, frame = cam.read()
        frame_width = int(cam.get(3))
        frame_height = int(cam.get(4))

    else:
        rval = False

    while rval:
        cv2.namedWindow(previewName, cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
        if (camID == 2):
            frame= cv2.flip(frame,-1)
       # cv2.setWindowProperty(previewName, cv2.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN, cv2.WINDOW_FULLSCREEN)
        cv2.imshow(previewName, frame)
      # cam.set(CV_CAP_PROP_SETTINGS, 0)
        rval, frame = cam.read()

        key = cv2.waitKey(20)
        if key == 115 :
            Cam1="Cam"+str(camID)+"_"+timestr
            ts=datetime.datetime.now()
            filename="{}.avi".format(Cam1+ts.strftime("%Y%m%d_%H-%M-%S"))
            out=cv2.VideoWriter(filename,cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('M','J', 'P','G'),10,(480,720))
            out.write(frame)
            if key == 27:
              print("Stopping recording")
              break
        if key == 27:  # exit on ESC
            break
    cv2.destroyWindow(previewName)

# Create threads as follows
thread1 = camThread("Camera 1", 0)
thread2 = camThread("Camera 2", 2)
thread3 = camThread("Camera 3", 3)
timestr=str(now.strftime("%Y%m%d_%H-%M-%S"))

print("Working Directory:")
print(timestr)

#thread1.start()
thread2.start()
thread3.start()
print()
print("Active threads", threading.activeCount())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from threading import Thread
import cv2
import time

class VideoWriterWidget(object):
    def __init__(self, video_file_name, src=0):
        # Create a VideoCapture object
        self.frame_name = str(src) # if using webcams, else just use src as it is.
        self.video_file = video_file_name
        self.video_file_name = video_file_name + '.avi'
        self.capture = cv2.VideoCapture(src)

        # Default resolutions of the frame are obtained (system dependent)
        self.frame_width = int(self.capture.get(3))
        self.frame_height = int(self.capture.get(4))

        # Set up codec and output video settings
        self.codec = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('M','J','P','G')
        self.output_video = cv2.VideoWriter(self.video_file_name, self.codec, 30, (self.frame_width, self.frame_height))

        # Start the thread to read frames from the video stream
        self.thread = Thread(target=self.update, args=())
        self.thread.daemon = True
        self.thread.start()

        # Start another thread to show/save frames
        self.start_recording()
        print('initialized {}'.format(self.video_file))

    def update(self):
        # Read the next frame from the stream in a different thread
        while True:
            if self.capture.isOpened():
                (self.status, self.frame) = self.capture.read()

    def show_frame(self):
        # Display frames in main program
        if self.status:
            cv2.imshow(self.frame_name, self.frame)

        # Press Q on keyboard to stop recording
        key = cv2.waitKey(1)
        if key == ord('q'):
            self.capture.release()
            self.output_video.release()
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            exit(1)

    def save_frame(self):
        # Save obtained frame into video output file
        self.output_video.write(self.frame)

    def start_recording(self):
        # Create another thread to show/save frames
        def start_recording_thread():
            while True:
                try:
                    self.show_frame()
                    self.save_frame()
                except AttributeError:
                    pass
        self.recording_thread = Thread(target=start_recording_thread, args=())
        self.recording_thread.daemon = True
        self.recording_thread.start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    src1 = 'Your link1'
    video_writer_widget1 = VideoWriterWidget('Camera 1', src1)
    src2 = 'Your link2'
    video_writer_widget2 = VideoWriterWidget('Camera 2', src2)
    src3 = 'Your link3'
    video_writer_widget3 = VideoWriterWidget('Camera 3', src3)

    # Since each video player is in its own thread, we need to keep the main thread alive.
    # Keep spinning using time.sleep() so the background threads keep running
    # Threads are set to daemon=True so they will automatically die 
    # when the main thread dies
    while True:
        time.sleep(5)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you're on the right track but I was unable to save a file with your code. Here's a video-stream-to-video widget using multithreading to obtain the frames. There are two threads for each camera stream:

- Thread #1 - Dedicated to only reading frames from the camera stream.
- Thread #2 - Dedicated for processing frames (showing and writing).

We separate reading frames from showing/writing because `cv2.VideoCapture.read()` is a blocking operation. Thus we read frames in its own independent thread to 'improve' FPS by reducing latency due to I/O operations. In addition, by isolating frame capture to its own thread, there will always be a frame ready to be processed instead of having to wait for the I/O operation to complete and return a new frame. In our second thread dedicated to processing, we are now freely able to show and save each frame to our output file.

Also by encapsulating all this into a single object, we can create a set of threads for each camera which scales easily no matter how many cameras are being used. Since each camera stream is spawned in a background thread, we must keep the main thread alive. Be sure to change the `src` string to your own camera. Here's an example of recording three video streams simultaneously.

[image]

```
from threading import Thread
import cv2
import time

class VideoWriterWidget(object):
    def __init__(self, video_file_name, src=0):
        # Create a VideoCapture object
        self.frame_name = str(src)
        self.video_file = video_file_name
        self.video_file_name = video_file_name + '.avi'
        self.capture = cv2.VideoCapture(src)

        # Default resolutions of the frame are obtained (system dependent)
        self.frame_width = int(self.capture.get(3))
        self.frame_height = int(self.capture.get(4))

        # Set up codec and output video settings
        self.codec = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('M','J','P','G')
        self.output_video = cv2.VideoWriter(self.video_file_name, self.codec, 30, (self.frame_width, self.frame_height))

        # Start the thread to read frames from the video stream
        self.thread = Thread(target=self.update, args=())
        self.thread.daemon = True
        self.thread.start()

        # Start another thread to show/save frames
        self.start_recording()
        print('initialized {}'.format(self.video_file))

    def update(self):
        # Read the next frame from the stream in a different thread
        while True:
            if self.capture.isOpened():
                (self.status, self.frame) = self.capture.read()

    def show_frame(self):
        # Display frames in main program
        if self.status:
            cv2.imshow(self.frame_name, self.frame)

        # Press Q on keyboard to stop recording
        key = cv2.waitKey(1)
        if key == ord('q'):
            self.capture.release()
            self.output_video.release()
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            exit(1)

    def save_frame(self):
        # Save obtained frame into video output file
        self.output_video.write(self.frame)

    def start_recording(self):
        # Create another thread to show/save frames
        def start_recording_thread():
            while True:
                try:
                    self.show_frame()
                    self.save_frame()
                except AttributeError:
                    pass
        self.recording_thread = Thread(target=start_recording_thread, args=())
        self.recording_thread.daemon = True
        self.recording_thread.start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    src1 = 'Your link1'
    video_writer_widget1 = VideoWriterWidget('Camera 1', src1)
    src2 = 'Your link2'
    video_writer_widget2 = VideoWriterWidget('Camera 2', src2)
    src3 = 'Your link3'
    video_writer_widget3 = VideoWriterWidget('Camera 3', src3)

    # Since each video player is in its own thread, we need to keep the main thread alive.
    # Keep spinning using time.sleep() so the background threads keep running
    # Threads are set to daemon=True so they will automatically die 
    # when the main thread dies
    while True:
        time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: Hi Nathancy, thank you so much for the detailed reply. I did try to use your code but it failed to display the stream and also record the videos after updating my source for the cameras. When I run the code, i get exceptions on the console and the program hangs and does not exit. So I have to force quite the application and so I have taken a snapshot of the the console for you to see what is happening. This is a link to the image: https://i.imgur.com/LhIAzSn.png. Could you please guide me as to why the line which displays the frame raises an exception when using the threading?

Comment: Since you're unable to display the stream, I have a feeling the `src` is wrong. From the docs it mentions that to use webcam, you pass an integer number to `cv2.VideoCapture()`. So maybe the `src` is a string instead of a integer. Try only playing one stream at a time and change `src1 = 'Your link1'` to `src1 = 0`

Comment: I did try with one stream at a time but that gave me the same error. But were you suggesting that I was passing a string to cv2.VideoCapture()?

Comment: No try pass a integer to `cv2.VideoCapture()`. When I was testing, I used my RTSP stream link which is a string but to use webcam, the [docs](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_video_display/py_video_display.html) say to use a integer.

Comment: Yes I was passing an integer, 0, 2 and 3.  And I got these exceptions and then it was hanging.

Comment: Oh try change `self.frame_name = src` to `self.frame_name = str(src)`

Comment: So I think the problem was because the function `cv2.imshow(str,np.array)` takes in a string as first parameter, but it was getting a integer

Comment: thank you so much for that, the suggested change worked. Could you tell me what you are trying to do with the sleep function here??

Comment: Awesome that's good to hear. So in your original question, you asked for a way to record video from a stream using multithreading. The method I used was exactly that but I decided to use two threads instead of one (the reasoning for two threads is up there). Since we create a new object for each stream in a separate independent thread, we essentially free up our main program to do whatever it wants. You can think of the camera threads as its own independent thing running in the background. But since we spawned it from the main thread, we need to keep the main thread 'alive'.

Comment: I did try to play with time.sleep () a bit, its because I am unable to exit the program consistently in a good way. I was trying to resize the window size to different dimensions and also trying to maximize the window, but then the behaviour is not consistent to exit the program. It was hanging sometimes and also i was trying just with two cameras and with some runs with the script, the second camera feed was not showing up. Any ideas on the inconsistent behaviour?

Comment: Weird, I'm not getting that behavior. To exit the program, press 'q' on any frame. It should close all the frames. It should load both cameras sequentially.

Comment: I know that s how we exit but this is what I was observing so was wondering if you could relate to it?

Comment: I was not able to replicate what you're experiencing. You may want to check each camera to ensure that you're able to open it

Comment: the cameras open but at times between the two cameras, one of them fail to show the feed. they both are cameras connected to the USB.

Comment: That may be a camera issue. I've tried with 5 cameras and it seems to be working fine. Try only use one and see if it fails to show the feed

Comment: with one camera it seemed to work fine but with multiple cameras coming into the picture, there was this inconsistency. So wanted to know, if there was something that I am missing out in this behaviour. did you try to play with the rsolution of the opencv window while displaying it? Did you find any differences?

Comment: I did not find any differences, if you wanted to resize the frames, you can modify the code with `cv2.resize()` before the frames are saved/shown. I did not experience any inconsistencies

Comment: Yes that s what I was doing. but I do not know the reason why it behaves like this. Maybe because its connected to the same usb bus?

Comment: Potentially? I haven't used webcam before with OpenCV but to use other webcams I believe you enter `1,2,3,...` depending on the USB number

Comment: Yes that is how we work with the webcams. Anyways thank you for your reply and this answer was useful for me.I have posted the answer with the str correction for the source.